# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. for php 5.6.33 and php 7.2.2 after ./configure

Tags: php, linux

[image]

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

for php 5.6.33 and php 7.2.2 
after `./configure` as shown in fig.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` if it's a debian based distro

Comment: you forgot to ask the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml2 library need to be installed.

If it's a Debian based distribution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```